# I am creating a release pipeline on Azure DevOps for deploying APIM APP. I have tasks in my release pipeline: AzureBlob File Copy task

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am creating a release pipeline on Azure DevOps for deploying APIM. I have task in my release pipeline AzureBlob File Copy task. The AzureBlob File Copy task throws the following error:
pload to container: 'mycontainer' in storage account: 'abc' with blob prefix: 'vd1' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.'

Comment: Can you share the YAML for your Azure Blob File task?

Comment: issue resolved, thanks for responding to me